# Jquery Mobile Dialog Form

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working with jQueryMobile and I want to use a form to input some values in a database.

I have a form which works and uses the test123.php to submit data to a database this:

```
  <form method="get" action="test123.php?test=1">
         <input type="submit" value="spiegel" />
  </form>
```

I get a button, but the new page is shown as a normal page.

With this solution:

```
  <a  data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" href="#test">
           spiegel
  </a>
```

I get a dialog with the same output (i get the message "spiegel").

But I want the confirmation site to appear as a dialog.

A link with data-rel"dialog" so i want to use my php site but i want to look it like a dialog after i submitted my data do a database. I'm not sure how to do this.

Thank you for your help

Comment: input values from a database? Forms are used to SUBMIT values TO a database. You don't really need the form but we do need more information to help you

Comment: I meant that i am using the form already to SUBMIT values TO a database. This is working. I just need that my confirmation Site which is just a phrase: (in this example: "spiegel") to popup as a dialog.

Comment: Okay. Now you got your dialog. But this is terribly unclear "my PHP site is not used"?? What does that even mean ??

Comment: ok. I'm sry, if i was unclear. I will try again. I have a form which works and uses the test123.php to submit data to a database. But i want that the confirmation site appears as a dialog as it is shown in the example below the form. A link with data-rel"dialog" so i want to use my php site but i want to look it like a dialog after i submitted my data do a database. Was it now clear? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
  <!--add all your jquery,jquery mobile as well as its CSS refrences here-->
 </head>
<body>
<div data-role = "page">
    <div data-role="header">
<a href="#login" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-icon="plus">opendialogpage</a>
</div>
    <div data-role="content">
<p>just for sample display</p></div>
</div>
    <div data-role="dialog" id="login">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="login_form">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label>USER NAME:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label>EMAIL ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" value=""/></div>
            </fieldset>  
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you want data from your PHP page to open in the dialog and not in the next page.

What your looking for is AJAX.

AJAX allows you to refresh and change part of your HTML page without changing the entire page.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'test123.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {spiegel : 'spiegel'}
   error : function (){ document.title='error'; }, 
  success: function (data) {
    $('#ajax_content').html(data);
}
```

});

So this function will return into variable data whatever was generated by `test123.php`

Link to Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too for a while.  Finally took a look at the html that jquery mobile creates for a dialog page.  Just create a page with the structure below, and it will always open as a dialog page (as though it had been opened from a link with `data-rel="dialog"`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Page Title</title> 
<!-- include your css, jquery, and jquery mobile files here -->
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="dialog">
<div data-role="content">   
<!-- content goes here -->
</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /dialog -->
</body>
</html>
```

All you are doing is changing `data-role="page"` to `data-role="dialog"`.